# Documentation on the value of $$ in a background process

Tags: bash, process, background-process

Is there a documentation on the value of `$$` in a background process in bash?

---

`man` claims that `$$` in a subshell is the PID of the main process.

According to the following documentation, a subshell is created through braces `(...)`, however, it seems `cmd &` is not officially a subshell.

https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap03.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12):

> Command substitution, commands
> that are grouped with parentheses, and **asynchronous lists** shall be
> executed in a subshell environment.

`cmd &` is an [asynchronous list](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_02).

---

And assuming (for the sake of the argument) that `cmd &` was *not* a subshell, then the only thing left would be the *main* shell environment, where `$$` would've given the PID of the main process just the same ;-)

---

Note: In bash, all the commands from a pipeline are run in subshells, too. In some other shells like ksh, the last command from a pipeline is run in the main shell environment. This will print `1` in `bash` and `3` in `ksh`:

```
a=1; a=2 | a=3; echo $a
```

Comment: bash 4.2+ _sometimes_ runs the last part of a foreground pipeline in the main shell; see [`shopt lastpipe`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few references to `$$` in the `man bash` documentation:

Special Parameters

> `$` Expands to the process ID of the shell. In a `()` subshell, it expands to the process ID of the current shell, not the subshell.

Shell Variables

> `BASHPID` Expands to the process ID of the current bash process.  This differs from `$$` under certain circumstances, such as subshells that do not require bash to be re-initialized.

COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT

> The shell has an execution environment, which consists of the following:
>
> - [...]
> - various process IDs, including those of background jobs, the value of `$$`, and the value of `PPID`

Empirically you can see that `$$` remains unchanged in a syntactic subshell, but that `$BASHPID` changes:

```
echo "$BASHPID - $$"                     # 23671 - 23671
( echo "$BASHPID - $$" )                 # 41199 - 23671
true | ( echo "$BASHPID - $$" ) | cat    # 41258 - 23671
```

Comment: I have seen the answers regarding subprocesses in other answers, I tested the value of `$$` in various cases. The only thing missing is a documentational link between `$$` and `&`. I want to see how future-proof the empirical results are.